# How to programmatically iterate datagrid rows?

Tags: winforms

I'm suddenly back to WinForms, after years of web development, and am having trouble  with something that should be simple.  I have an `ArrayList` of business objects bound to a  Windows Forms `DataGrid`.  I'd like the user to be able to edit the cells, and when finished,  press a Save button.  At that point I'd like to iterate the all the rows and columns in the  `DataGrid` to find any changes, and save them to the database.  But I can't find a way to  access the `DataGrid` rows.

I'll also want to validate individual cells real time, as they are edited, but I'm pretty  sure that can be done.  (Maybe not with an `ArrayList` as the `DataSource`?)  But as for iterating the `DataGrid`, I'm quite surprised it doesn't seem possible.

Must I really stuff my business objects data into datatables in order to use the datagrid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
foreach(var row in DataGrid1.Rows)
{
  DoStuff(row);
}
//Or ---------------------------------------------   
foreach(DataGridRow row in DataGrid1.Rows)
{
  DoStuff(row);
}
//Or ---------------------------------------------
for(int i = 0; i< DataGrid1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
  DoStuff(DataGrid1.Rows[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object cell = myDataGrid[row, col];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything about WinForms 3.0 that is so much better than in 1.1

I don't know about 3.0, but you can write code in VS 2008 which runs on the .NET 2.0 framework. (So, you get to use the latest C# language, but you can only use the 2.0 libraries)

This gets you Generics (`List<DataRow>` instead of those GodAwful ArrayLists) and a ton of other stuff, you'll literally end up writing 3x less code.

Answer (score -2):

Aha, I was really just testing everyone once again!  :)  The real answer is, you rarely need to iterate the datagrid.  Because even when binding to an ArrayList, the binding is 2 way.  Still, it is handy to know how to itereate the grid directly, it can save a few lines of code now and then.

But NotMyself and Orion gave the better answers:  Convince the stakeholders to move up to a higher version of C#, to save development costs and increase maintainability and extensability.